# Why is my mergesort using threads slower than without using them?

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex, mergesort

I am a student and I need to implement Mergesort program in C using threads and fork(). Implementation without paralelisation was premade by school assistant. So far I implemented thread paralelisation but the program is much slower than running it without threads...

I am reading numbers and measuring time from premade file with:

```
$ time cat rand_stevila.bin | ./mergeSort 10000
```

when I'm ordering with threads I run with:

```
$ time cat rand_stevila.bin | ./mergeSort 10000 -t
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wait.h>

void printHelp(int argc, char **argv);
void submergeSortSimple(int *array, int min1, int max1, int min2, int max2);
void submergeSortProc(int *array, int min1, int max1, int min2, int max2);
void submergeSortThread(int *array, int min1, int max1, int min2, int max2);
void mergeSort(int *array, int min, int max, void(*submergeSort)(int *, int, int, int, int));
void merge(int *arr,int min,int mid,int max);

int max_paralelizacij;
pthread_mutex_t mtx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

struct {
    int *array;
    int min;
    int max;
    void (*function)(int *, int, int, int, int);
} typedef thread_args;

void *thread_fun(void *args) {
    thread_args *thr_arg = (thread_args*)args;
    mergeSort((*thr_arg).array, (*thr_arg).min, (*thr_arg).max, (*thr_arg).function);
    return 0;
}

// preprosta implementacija mergeSort rekurzije,
// samo klicemo margeSort za levo in desno polovico
// v istem procesu/isti niti
void submergeSortSimple(int *array, int min1, int max1, int min2, int max2) {
    mergeSort(array, min1, max1, submergeSortSimple);
    mergeSort(array, min2, max2, submergeSortSimple);
}

// TODO: funkcija ki paralelizira sortiranje z uporabo procesov
// za preprosto paralelizacijo samo izvedemo vsak klic mergeSort 
// funkcije v svojem procesu, in počakamo, da se klica zaključita
void submergeSortProc(int *array, int min1, int max1, int min2, int max2) {
    printf("implementacija submergeSortProc manjka\n");
    return;
}

// TODO: funkcija, ki paralelizira sortiranje z uporabo niti
// za preprosto paralelizacijo samo izvedemo vsak klic mergeSort 
// funkcije v svoji niti, in počakamo, da se klica zaključita
void submergeSortThread(int *array, int min1, int max1, int min2, int max2) {
    pthread_t tid1, tid2;
    thread_args arg1,arg2;

    arg1.array = array;
    arg1.min = min1;
    arg1.max = max1;
    arg1.function = submergeSortThread;

    arg2.array = array;
    arg2.min = min2;
    arg2.max = max2;
    arg2.function = submergeSortThread;

    pthread_create(&tid1, 0, &thread_fun, &arg1);
    pthread_join(tid1, NULL); 

    pthread_create(&tid2, 0, &thread_fun, &arg2);
    pthread_join(tid2, NULL); 
    return;
}

// mergeSort in merge funkciji
// ti dve izvajata dejansko sortiranje

// void mergeSort(int *array, int min, int max, void(*submergeSort)(int *, int, int, int, int))
//
// int *array
//   kazalec na tabelo števil, ki jih urejamo
//
// int min, int max
//   indeks prvega in zadnjega števila v tabeli, 
//   označujeta interval, ki ga sortiramo
//
// void (*submergeSort)(int *array, int min1, int max1, int min2, int max2)
//   kazalec na funkcijo, ki naj kliče mergeSort za dva podintervala 
//   in vrne, ko sta oba intervala sortirana
void mergeSort(int *array, int min, int max, void (*submergeSort)(int *, int, int, int, int)) {
    int mid;

    if (min < max) {
        mid = (min + max) / 2;
        submergeSort(array, min, mid, mid+1, max);
        merge(array, min, mid, max);
    }
}

// void merge(int *arr, int min,int mid,int max)
// 
// int *arr
//   kazalec na tabelo
//
// int min, int mid, int max
//   indeksi na del tabele, ki jih je potrebno združiti
//   min je začetni indeks prve podtabele, mid je zadnji indeks
//   prve podtabele in max je zadnji indeks druge podtabele
// 
// metoda zdruzi dve sosednji sortirani podtabeli,
// tako da je nova podtabela tudi sortirana
void merge(int *arr, int min, int mid, int max) {
    // drugi korak algoritma mergeSort
    int *tmp = malloc((max - min + 1) * sizeof(int));
    int i, j, k, m;
    j = min;
    m = mid + 1;

    for (i = min; j <= mid && m <= max; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx); 
        if (arr[j] <= arr[m]) {
            tmp[i - min] = arr[j];
            j++;
        } else {
            tmp[i - min] = arr[m];
            m++;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx); 
    }
    if (j > mid) {
        for (k = m; k <= max; k++) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx); 
            tmp[i - min] = arr[k];
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx); 
            i++;
        }
    } else {
        for (k = j; k <= mid; k++) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx); 
            tmp[i - min] = arr[k];
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
            i++;
        }
    }
    for (k = min; k <= max; k++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx); 
        arr[k] = tmp[k - min];
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    }

    free(tmp);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
#define NO_PAR 0 
#define PROC_PAR 1
#define THREAD_PAR 2
    int technique = NO_PAR;
    void (*submergeSortFun)(int *, int, int, int, int);
    submergeSortFun = submergeSortSimple;
    while (1) {
        int c;
        c = getopt(argc, argv, "ptn:");
        //printf("while\n");
        if (c == -1) {
            break;
        }
        switch (c) {
          case 'p':
            technique = PROC_PAR;
            submergeSortFun = submergeSortProc;
            break;
          case 't':
            technique = THREAD_PAR;
            submergeSortFun = submergeSortThread;
            //printf("HALOOOOOO\n");
            break;
          case 'n':
            //printf("Vrednost: %s\n",optarg);
            max_paralelizacij = atoi(optarg);
            //printf("Max par: %d\n",max_paralelizacij); 
            break;
          default:
            //printf("more printat\n");
            printHelp(argc, argv);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    //printf("\nHIER\n");

    int i;
    int size;
    int *arr;
    if (optind >= argc) {
        printHelp(argc, argv);
        return -1;
    }

    size = atoi(argv[optind]);

    // TODO: inicializacija za razlicne tehnike 
    switch (technique) {
      case NO_PAR:
        arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
        break;
      case PROC_PAR:
        // inicializacija za uporabo procesov
        // ustvariti je potrebno deljen pomnilnik, semafor, ...
        dprintf(2, "not implemented\n");
        exit(-1);
        break;
      case THREAD_PAR:
        //printf("\ntechnique\n");
        arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*size);

        // inicializacija za uporabo procesov
        // tukaj potrebujete morebitne sinhronizacijske strukture

        //dprintf(2, "not implemented\n");
        //exit(-1);
        break;
    }
    char buffer[101];
    for (i = 0; i < size; i += 1) {
        //printf("ines erbus\n");
        // preberi binarne vrednosti
        read(0, &arr[i], 4);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        //printf("Serbus ines\n");
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n\n\nKonec Filanja\n\n\n\n");
    //printf("test\n");
    mergeSort(arr, 0, size - 1, submergeSortFun);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // TODO: ciscenje za razlicnimi tehnikami
    switch (technique) {
      case NO_PAR:
        free(arr);
        break;
      case PROC_PAR:
        dprintf(2, "not implemented\n");
        exit(-1);
        break;
      case THREAD_PAR:
        dprintf(2, "not implemented\n");
        exit(-1);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}

void printHelp(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("uporaba\n");
    printf("%s <opcija> <n>\n", argv[0]);
    printf("\tn je število celih števil prebranih z standardnega vhoda\n");
    printf("\tfunkcije prebere n*4 bajtov v tabelo in jih sortira\n");
    printf("opcije:\n");
    printf("-p\n");
    printf("\tparalelizacija s pomočjo procesov\n");
    printf("-t\n");
    printf("\tparalelizacija s pomočjo niti\n");
}
```

Comment: There is a `pthread_join` between the two `pthread_create` calls. From the [pthread_join man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html): "The pthread_join() function waits for the thread specified by thread to terminate". It means the second thread will not be created until the first thread exits.

Comment: That's why a [mcve] is required. You need to distill your problems down to focus on the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You create multiple threads but you do not let them run in parallel: you should change `submergeSortThread` to group the thread creation and move the wait to the end:

```
pthread_create(&tid1, 0, &thread_fun, &arg1);
pthread_create(&tid2, 0, &thread_fun, &arg2);
pthread_join(tid1, NULL); 
pthread_join(tid2, NULL);
```

The program might still be slower if you create threads for very small tasks, where the overhead of thread creation becomes significant in front of the benefits of parallel execution. There should also be little to no gain from creating more threads than there are cores in your system, as onl so many threads can execute in parallel (in the best case).

Finally, you should try and avoid the need for mutex locks by making sure the different threads do not access the same data concurrently. The overhead of these `pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);` / `pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);` pairs is significant.

Comment: How can I ensure that Threads don't access same data concurrently, wihout using mutex?

Comment: @AljažGornik: by assigning threads separate parts of the array *and* the temporary array. You can achieve that by using the same offsets in the temporary array as in the array to be sorted.